# How to invoke Talend job upon s3 file created event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, talend

I'm using Talend as my ETL tool which takes data from S3 bucket, cleans and then load into Redshift. But in case of real-time ETL processing, how to invoke ETL(Talend job) upon file created event in S3?

Comment: Talend does have a file watcher component (tWaitForFile) which can be used on a normal file system.  Not sure if it will work on a remote S3 folder.  You would need to schedule the Talend job so it keeps looking for the file.  The Talend file watcher though is fairly limited.  We tend to use another file watcher program, then we kick off our job in one of two ways:  export your job as a webservice and install in Tomcat, or use the TAC for scheduling.

Comment: @ELaRoche, what other kind of file watcher program is available for this?

Comment: Simple create a job that **initially checks if file available in s3. If it is available proceed your job, else end the job**. Based on your requirement schedule the job frequency like every 1 min, etc

Comment: We use a very expensive scheduling tool that has a nice file watcher built in.  If the tWaitForFile works on S3 file system (it might, but I have only used it on Windows network drives, so I can't say) then give it a try.  Its primitive but you can schedule it once a day, and it will check many times, rather than scheduling your job many times a day.